# Proving L' Hospital's Rule

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives, indeterminate-forms

Referring to the proof L'Hospital's first rule in Bartle and Sherbert, *Introduction to Real Analysis*, page 189, Fourth Edition.

By the proof can one conclude that if $L$ is finite then $h(x)=L$ for some $x \in (a,c)$, where $h(x)=f'(x)/g'(x)$?[image: I have attached a copy of the proof.]?

Comment: Add a link of the book page you are talking

Comment: You should make the question self-contained by including the proof in your question. If the proof is long, provide an excerpt with enough context to see what is going on in the proof.

Comment: Many people won't know that book, maybe not even have access to it.

Comment: You cannot conclude this, consider $a=0$, $f(x) = x+x^2$, $g(x) = x$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you got this idea from this part of the proof:

> Case(a): If $L\in \Bbb R$ and if $\varepsilon > 0$ is given, there exists $c \in (a,b)$ such that $$L- \varepsilon < \dfrac{f'(u)}{g'(u)} < L + \varepsilon \qquad\text{for  } u \in (a,c),$$

That statement is just the definition of $$\lim_{x \to a+} \dfrac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} = L$$ which is an assumption for case (a) of the proof. There is nothing in it that requires $h = f'/g'$ to actually equal $L$. It could be always above $L$ or always below $L$. If you choose a smaller $\varepsilon$, it just means that the $c$ promised by the definition will have to be closer to $a$.